# Race condition with replica read database with Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js, psql, database-replication

We are using Sequelize with a AWS Aurora Postgresql database with a read and write database. Sequelize is configured to use the read replica and write databases.

We have a `users` table and `follows` table. The `User` object type has fields that are subqueries, for instance the field followingCount on the user:

```
...
followingCount: {
  type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt),
  resolve(user) {
    return db.Follower.count({
      where: { followerId: user.id, status: "Approved" }
    });
  }
},
```

When we add a record to the `follows` table for a user, then return that user instance, the `followingCount` is not updated. I'm 99% confident this is because it's reading from the replica/read database which does not have the data. I've verified this by disabling the replica and seeing the issue disappear.

I'm hesitant to add the `useMaster` option to these fields, as it negates our concurrency strategy.

Here is the exact code I am calling:

```
const followingUser = await db.User.findOne({
  where: {
    id
  }
});

await db.Follower.create({
  followerId: getCurrentUserId(context),
  followingId: id,
  status: followingUser.privateProfile ? "Pending" : "Approved"
});

return followingUser.reload();
```

The `followingCount` field on the user instance(`followingUser`) isn't returning the newest count even though it exists on the master/write db.

What options are there? Is there someway I can wrap my mutations in a block so that anything executed within uses the Master/Write database? Would wrapping it in a transaction help, and if so how do I pass the transaction down to my

ANY help appreciated

`psql 9.6.8`

`sequelize 4.38.0`

Comment: My dear, Can I have your comment on z answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this by calling `reload()` on the DB Object I was returning, and passing it `useMaster: true`

`followingUser.reload({ useMaster: true });`

I created a ticket with sequelize that has more context if it's helpful for anyone: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9971

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL replication can be made in various ways:

- Synchronous
- Asynchronous

If you are running **asynchronous replication**, data might hit the slave AFTER a transaction has been committed on the primary server (master). There is usually a small replication delay.

You can replicate **synchronously** to as many slaves as you want to ensure that a COMMIT is only valid once it has been confirmed by the desired number of PostgreSQL servers.

#### Synchronous transaction can return only if a sufficient number of slaves have confirmed the write.

so I think you are using asynchronous replication and you need to shift to synchronous replication.

https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/services/postgresql-replication/synchronous-synchronous-replication/

In order to set up synchronous replication, you need to configure synchronous_standby_name and synchronous_commit parameters in the postgresql.conf file. The synchronous_commit parameter can have following values: off, on, remote_write, remote_apply (a Postgres 9.6 feature), and local.

[More on how to set up sync replication](https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/cheat-sheet-configuring-streaming-synchronous-replication-postgresql)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. It doesnt lool like AWS Aurora offers synchronous replication though https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/faqs/#high-availability-and-replication